# C How to write enlarged digits

Tags: c

i need to write a program to read in a 2-digit binary number and print it out in an enlarged format( 7 x 7 grid). I can assume to only have an input of 2 binary digits. For example

```
input=01 
output=
....... ...1...
.00000. ..11...
.0...0. .1.1...
.0...0. ...1...
.0...0. ...1...
.00000. ...1...
....... .11111.
```

My attempt

```
int input;
scanf("%d", &input);

if(input=0) 
printf(".......
        .00000.
        .0...0.
        .0...0.
        .0...0.
        .00000.
        .......");
```

I always get an error message

Comment: You need `if (input == 0) {}`. You are instead assigning a value of `0` to `input` here.

Comment: "I always get an error message" It is more useful to post the exact text of the error message than only describe it.  It improves the post.

Answer (score 2):

1. You need to store the data in a two dimensional array. because it is necessary to display two numerical data on one line.
2. You must enter numbers as strings or enter one digit at a time. if you enter it as a series of numbers, the leading 0 will be lost. E.g input:`01` evaluate as `1`.

So, like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define HEIGHT 7
#define WIDTH  7

char zero[HEIGHT][WIDTH] = {
    ".......",
    ".00000.",
    ".0...0.",
    ".0...0.",
    ".0...0.",
    ".00000.",
    "......."
};
char one[HEIGHT][WIDTH] = {
    "...1...",
    "..11...",
    ".1.1...",
    "...1...",
    "...1...",
    "...1...",
    ".11111."
};

int main(void){
    char ch, input[3];
    if(1==scanf("%2[01]", input)){
        for(int i = 0; i < HEIGHT; ++i){
            for(int j = 0; ch = input[j]; ++j){
                if(j)
                    putchar(' ');//separator
                switch(ch){
                case '0':
                    printf("%.*s", WIDTH, zero[i]);
                    break;
                case '1':
                    printf("%.*s", WIDTH, one[i]);
                    break;
                }
            }
            puts("");
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to actually insert new line characters (i.e. `\n`):

```
int input; 
scanf("%d", &input); 
if(input==0) 
printf(".......\n.00000.\n.0...0.\n.0...0.\n.0...0.\n.00000.\n.......");
```